# Notepad++ html tag / string (a href) replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I found another post that uses the following regex `<a[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>` it works great however I want to use a capture group to target URLs that have the following 4 letters in them `RTRD`.

I used `<a[^>]*>(RTRD+)</a>` and that did not work.

`<a href="http:\\something.RTRD.html">TESTER</a>` I want to remove the URL and leave TESTER

`<a href="http:\\something.RTRB.html">LEAVE</a>` I want to not touch this one.

Comment: Your RegExp is targeting the link text currently, not the `href` attribute...

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54439558/edit) and add sample input text and expected result.

Comment: It may work great but it never guarantees to keep doing so.

Comment: So what you mean is to remove the anchor element (<a> tags and everything inside) and leave only the text when that text contains any of the letters R, T or D anywhere in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One that will work: `<a\s[^>]*href\=[\"][^\"]*(RTRD)[^\"]*[\"][^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>`

Decomposition:

`<a\s[^>]*` find opening a tag with space followed by some arguments

`href\=[\"][^\"]*` find href attribute with " opening and then multiple non " closing

`(RTRD)` Your Key group

`[^\"]*[\"]` Find remainder of argument and closing "

`[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>` The remainder of the original regex

---

Things your original RegExp would match:
`<a stuffhere!!.,?>RTRDDD</a>`
`<a>RTRD</a>`

Decomposing your RegExp:

`<a[^>]*>` Look for opening tag with any properties

`(RTRD+)` Look for the `RTRD` group but also match one or more D

`<a[^>]*>` Look for closing tag

Comment: This removes the URL but leaves the word RTRD. I was trying to leave the name TESTER in place. I have my Replace with set to `\1`

Comment: Try setting your replace to `\2` - which is the second capture group `([^<]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a[^>]*RTRD[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>` here.

Inside the opening tag (`<a[^>]*>`) should be the pattern `RTRD` somewhere. This can be done by replacing `[^>]*` with `[^>]*RTRB[^>]*`which is simply

- `[^>]*` Anything thats not a `>`(closing tag)
- `RTRB` The pattern `RTRB`
- `[^>]*` Again anything thats not a `>`

But caution: This also matches `<aRTRB>test</a>` or `<a id="RTRB">blubb</a>`

And if you have any other way than using Regex on HTML, use that way (string operations etc)